# Intent.getAction() throws NullPointerException in RemoteViewsFactory [AppWidget]

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-appwidget, remoteview

I'm trying to modify data on certain action but it throws NPE.

```
if("Button1_OnClickTag".equals(mIntent.getAction())){
        Collections.sort(mCollections, Anlik.COMPARE_BY_BIRIM);
        Log.d("****CollectionSize****", "initDataFromService_if: "+mCollections.size());
        notify();
    }
```

I'm using this piece in data initialization of my RemoteViesFactory. I don't know if this is the right way to do it. If not can you suggest any other way(s)?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
code flow comes to that point by following

```
if(Button1_OnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", context.getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        widgetIdupdate=sharedPreferences.getInt("mWidgetId", 66);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Category1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //WidgetDataProvider.modifData();
        Log.d("****ONCLICK WIDGETID", "onReceive: " + widgetIdupdate);
        RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.mudo_life_widget);
        mView.setRemoteAdapter(widgetIdupdate, R.id.list,intent);
        onUpdate(context);
    }
```

in my AppWidgetProvider than,

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

    WidgetDataProvider dataProvider = new WidgetDataProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), intent);
    return dataProvider;
}
```

}

in WidgetService and when it creates WidgetDataProvider

```
public WidgetDataProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {mContext = context; mIntent=intent;}
```

so I think it is already assigned to `Button1_OnClick` .
Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Very low information provided. Can you provide more code and logs?